# Hashing a seed together with a block counter and using as a encipherment scheme: Will this have the same security in bits as the seed used?

Tags: hash, keys, entropy

A user of this forum said that the [whole entropy of a seed goes to the hashed result if using a counter](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/102238/89581) and also that is suitable for key generation even if the internal state or digest size of the hash function is smaller of that of seed.

Let's suppose I have a seed with an entropy of 512-bits and hash it with a counter using a hash function with half of the seed size in bits as Blake2s (256-bits digest size).

I hash the seed in this way

$$H(S||00) || H(S||01) || H(S||02) || H(S||03) || \cdots$$

$H$ is the hash function, $S$ is the seed and $00, 01, 02, 03$ the block counter.

After this I make an encipherment scheme just XOR'ing the result in the plaintext.

My question is:

Will I have the same cryptographic strength of the seed used even if the seed size is larger than the hash output or its internal state?

Comment: One cannot increase the input entropy without additional entropy where Hash functions are actually reduce the entropy, well a little [see](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/71468/18298). You may consider that your security at most is $\min\{\text{input},\text{output}\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will $H(S\mathbin\|\mathtt{00})\mathbin\|H(S\mathbin\|\mathtt{01})\mathbin\|H(S\mathbin\|\mathtt{02})\mathbin\|H(S\mathbin\|\mathtt{03})\mathbin\|\ldots$ have the same cryptographic strength of the seed used even if the seed size is larger than the hash output or its internal state?

If we model $H$ as an ideal hash, that is as a random function with fixed size output: essentially† yes. For that model of the hash, each segment $H(S\mathbin\|\mathtt{uv})$ of the overall result for a particular input $F$ is independent of the others segments for that particular input $F$, and of every other segments for other inputs $F$.

For $H$ a practical hash: not quite, at least because the hash structure limits the number of possible outputs for any fixed size of $S$. For SHA-256 or any [Merkle–Damgård](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction) hash with block size much larger than the state/output size, the worst case is when $S$ is exactly a multiple of the block size of the hash (512-bit for SHA-256): the Merkle–Damgård structure "limits" the number of states of the hash after processing $S$ to $2^{256}$, the multiple instances of $H$ are in the same 256-bit state at this point, thus there are at most $2^{256}$ output states for the overall output.

On the other hand, that's purely theoretical: 256-bit entropy is plenty enough, SHA-256 generally aims at "only" 128-bit security, and if we want more there's SHA-512.

Note that if we use $H(\mathtt{00}\mathbin\|S)\mathbin\|H(\mathtt{01}\mathbin\|S)\mathbin\|H(\mathtt{02}\mathbin\|S)\mathbin\|H(\mathtt{03}\mathbin\|S)\mathbin\|\ldots$ we somewhat improve things, because the multiple hashes no longer are in the same state, thus there can be much more entropy in the overall output.

---

† Even a perfect hash is bound to reduce entropy, but that's only slightly, see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/24660/555); and this effect is very small in the context of the question.

Comment: You say about Merkle–Damgård constructions, does the same applies to Merkle tree based hash functions?

Comment: @phantomcraft: It think the situation with a Merkle tree based hash is in between that for a Merkle–Damgård hash $H(S\mathbin\|\mathtt{00})\mathbin\|H(S\mathbin\|\mathtt{01})\mathbin\|H(S\mathbin\|\mathtt{02})\mathbin\|H(S\mathbin\|\mathtt{03})\mathbin\|\ldots$ (minimum entropy, potentialy down to the hash size) and $H(\mathtt{00}\mathbin\|S)\mathbin\|H(\mathtt{01}\mathbin\|S)\mathbin\|H(\mathtt{02}\mathbin\|S)\mathbin\|H(\mathtt{03}\mathbin\|S)\mathbin\|\ldots$ (maximum entropy, near the output width).

Comment: And about H(H(F) || 00) || H(H(F) || 01) || H(H(F) || 02) || H(H(F) || 03) || .. ? How does it compare to H(00||S) || H(01||S) || H(02||S) || H(03||S) || ... ?  -- If I use H(00||S) || H(01||S) || H(02||S) || H(03||S) || ... instead of H(S||00) || H(S||01) || H(S||02) || H(S||03) || ..., the answer to my question would be "yes"?